# 'next_or_number' => 'next' not working - need to show only next/previous buttons in Wordpress pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am trying to remove numbers from pagination links on a paginated Wordpress post to leave only next/previous buttons. I have the code as follows and it still does not work as required. If I set a display:none; css rule to the  tags within the .paging p class this affects all links including the next/previous links as the links do not have a separate class to them.

```
<?php
wp_link_pages(array(
'before'           => '<p class="paging" style="margin-bottom: 5em;">' . __(''),
'after'            => '</p>',
'next_or_number'   => 'next', # activate parameter overloading
'nextpagelink'     => __('<span class="pagelink right">NEXT</span>'),
'previouspagelink' => __('<span class="pagelink left">PREVIOUS</span>'),
'pagelink'         => '%',
'echo'             => 1 )
); ?>
```

Here is an example of a post illustrating the problem: http://famtrav.staging.wpengine.com/destinations/uk/15-fun-things-july-2016/

Is there another way of me achieving the required result? I hope this makes sense. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this. The problem was caused by conflicting code. Specifically the wp_link_pages function was being defined both in the themes functions.php file and in the post-template.php file within the /wp-includes/ folder with instructions in one incidence contradicting the other. I commented out the instructions in the functions.php file and altered the post-template.php file with the correct code and this solved the problem.

Comment: You should never edit the core WP files, as this will most likely be reverted when you upgrade Wordpress. You shouldn't need to define the function in your functions file, you just insert it on your page template file where you want the links to appear - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages